# how to add a different class / style to wordpress posts?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles

I am trying to add a different class to specific posts which would call through a different style. I have played with the post_class function a little but i still have next to no clue how i could accomplish this, any ideas?

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $c = 0;while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $c++;
if( $c == 3) {
    $style = 'third';
    $c = 0;
}
else $style='';
?>
<div <?php post_class($style) ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

i tried adding this, the creating a custom style for it that just changed the color of the background and text

Would I be able to edit how the posts look on the home page with these though, that's what i am after if so i could of fixed this quickly instead of finding that obscure code :D

Comment: post some code or what you have tried or what problem your facing to do this

Comment: You could use the regular post-classes usually added by wordpress to the body. Every post has a unique ID and a class like `postid-206`. You can now use this class in a selector to style what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div <?php post_class($style) ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

check what class names this code is creating by using firebug or view source
you'll probably see something like this

```
<div class="divclassname" id="post-206">
```

Now, in the css stylesheet loaded with the page you need to make up new rules based on either the value of class (divclassname) or id (post-205) as follows.

```
.divclassname {
background-color: #f3f3f3;
color: #ffffff;
}

#post-205 {
background-color: #cccccc;
color: #a19402;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like dynamic Id you are using.

```
<div class="post-class-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside your loop:

```
$classes = array(
    0=>'first-column',
    1=>'second-column',
    2=>'third-column'
);
$i = 0;
```

In your loop :

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($classes[$i++%3]); ?>>
```

output like :

```
<article class="first-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="second-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="third-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="first-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="second-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="third-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
```